# Why are there suffix versions with code names for Delphi versions?

Tags: discussion, tags, versions

Why are Delphi tags in the the form of `delphi-{version}-{codename}` such as [delphi-11-alexandria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-11-alexandria) instead of `delphi-{version}`?

I'm guessing this makes it hard to filter.

Comment: Seems like a question better asked to the people who created the tags... You can see who created them in the tag info page. For instance, [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) created [tag:delphi-10-seattle], and appears to be the top answerer in many of those tags...

Comment: Why would this make it hard to filter? Having the codename there makes it easier to find the tag if you know *either* the version number *or* the codename.

Comment: Those are not really codenames, but marketing names. Tags simply follow vendor naming scheme. Also many developers refer to particular version only by name, omitting version number, so having full name in tag makes it easier to figure out to which version Q/A refers to.

Comment: For Visual Studio there are no version tags at all - all are product names like VS-2022 instead of VS-17... so adding codenames does not sound unusual.